Anime or manga with a tattooed character who can use a floating arrow
This anime or manga had one character I can remember somewhat clearly. The character uses a floating arrow that flies around at the users will, it has a red string attached to it or its a streak of light from said arrow. And the arrow has some red glowing accents on it. I think the character had tattoos on them, could be wrong though, I also think they had darker skin like grey or something. They had black hair if I can remember correctly and I think their name started with a 'Y'.

Guardians of the galaxy.  Yondu.  Had an arrow he could control. link

Was Yondu in an anime? Or one of the What If? Episodes?

@Radhil There's an animated series named Guardians of the Galaxy. Like Avengers Assemble, it's heavily influenced by the MCU's style https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3bQ_v5hM4s This is the same style that's being used ever since Ultimate Spider-Man

As was pointed out in the comments, you could be thinking of Marvel's Yondu. The main difference is that the character does not have black hair, but rather a cybernetic attachment that resembles a red mohawk. An animated version of the character appear in the Guardians of the Galaxy series, as seen in this clip:



An alternate version of the character appeared in What If...? season 1 episode 2. The character and the arrow can be seen in the show's trailer, around the 1:54 mark:



After the events of Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 the "mohawk" and the arrow are passed on to Yondu's first mate, Kraglin.
